# mootools: help loading multiple, per-page, Asset.javascript files

Tags: file, mootools, assets

i want to load an array of page-specific external .js files.  in the past, i did it through PHP at the top of each page, like so:

```
<?php
  $jsFiles = array("file01.js", "file02.js", ...);
  include("header.php");
?>
```

the `header.php` file loaded the files like so:

```
foreach ($jsFiles as $file) {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='_js/$file'></script> \n";
}
```

but now i need to do this all in JS because i have to load these files AFTER domready which is checked and fired in the `header.php` file...

this is the idea of what i want and i KNOW IT IS NOT CORRECT CODE, so rein in the comments! it is a conceptual construct.

```
for (file in jsFiles) {
  console.log('loading ' + file);
  Asset.javascript(file);
};
```

and, yup, i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065725/getscript-equivalent-in-mootools) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238117/mootools-check-for-css-or-js-files); close, but not quite.

questions i have are:

1) how to create the arrays on a per-page basis

2) how to load that array properly using the Asset class

thanks.

WR!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how you create the arrays is up to you. you can define an array with an array literal like so:

```
var filesToLoad = ["foo.js", "bar.js"];
// or even from a flat string...
var files = "foo.js,bar.js",
    filesToLoad = foo.split(",");
```

you can also setup a global js structure based upon something that identifies what page you are on, eg:

```
var pageAssets = {};
pageAssets["*"] = ["common.js"];
pageAssets["home"] = ["foo.js","bar.js"];
pageAssets["about"] = ["foo.js","bar.js","about.js"];

// in domready determine what to load...
var id = document.id("body").get("id");

// see down for explanation...
Asset.javascripts(pageAssets[id], {
    onComplete: function() {
        alert("all js loaded");
    }
});
```

if the order of loading then does not matter, you can use plain `Asset.javascript` as described:

```
filesToLoad.each(function(file) {
    new Asset.javascript(file);
});
```

the downside to all that is that this is async lazyloading. meaning that if you run a line immediately underneath that instantiates something based upon what you think you loaded, it will likely fail unless you're on a lan with primed cache.

I have extended Asset.js to support this:

```
Asset.javascripts = function(sources, options) {
    // load an array of js dependencies and fire events as it walks through
    options = Object.merge({
        onComplete: Function.from,
        onProgress: Function.from
    }, options);
    var counter = 0, todo = sources.length;

    var loadNext = function() {
        if (sources[0])
            source = sources[0];

        Asset.javascript(source, {
            onload: function() {
                counter++;
                options.onProgress.call(this, counter, source);
                sources.erase(source);

                if (counter == todo)
                    options.onComplete.call(this, counter);
                else
                    loadNext();
            }
        });
    };

    loadNext();
};
```

you just pass on the array as the `sources` argument and can set an onComplete and onProgress events. this also ensures FIFO from the array so if your dependency order matters, this will be fine.

the example i wrote / orig blog post is here: http://fragged.org/lazyloading-multiple-sequential-javascript-dependencies-in-mootools_1389.html

you should also read up about `Require.js` / AMD to make things more resilient from a dependency standpoint.

have fun.

Comment: my night for answers!  :)  thanks again Dimitar.  everytime i think i get a head around JS, something new pops up and blows my doors off.  this is good stuff!  :)  WR!