# Javascript array to defer js loading joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, mootools

I am deferring the loading of some js files in my Joomla template. This works fine

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function downloadJSAtOnload() {
            var element = document.createElement("script");
            element.src = "/pathto.js";
            document.body.appendChild(element);
        }
        if (window.addEventListener)
            window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
        else if (window.attachEvent)
            window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
        else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
    </script>
```

However, I have about a dozen js files to load like this and for each one I'm having to use the same block of code as above with just the pathto.js being different.

My Javascript abilities are pretty rubbish. Is it possible to put all the js files into an array and then just go through them one by one using the same block of code without having to repeat the same block over and over?

What I'd like is something like

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function downloadJSAtOnload() {
            var element = document.createElement("script");
            element.src = AN ARRAY OF JS FILES;
            document.body.appendChild(element);
        }
        FOR EACH ITEM IN THE ARRAY
            if (window.addEventListener)
                window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
            else if (window.attachEvent)
                window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
            else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
    </script>
```

Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: you should use Assets.js from mootools-more - http://mootools.net/more/docs/1.5.1/Utilities/Assets, and you can make it work with multiples - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665217/mootools-help-loading-multiple-per-page-asset-javascript-files - or better yet, use a real loader like requireJS :)

Comment: more upto date. http://jsfiddle.net/fc3c0u9v/ - keep in mind this is sequential loading, if 1 dep fails, chain will fail and `onComplete` won't call.

Comment: thanks Dimitar - that last one appears to work. Is it possible to make them async loading rather than sequential though?

Comment: sure, if you don't care about the order in which they come in... you could even wrap the calls into promises or whatever - otherwise, replace with a normal .each loop and fire an onComplete when len is done, without the check if remaining. ideally they should be configurable, you may want to load a>b>c,d,e

Answer (score 0):

Actually the loop should be in the function.

Here's what the function should be (I haven't tested it):

```
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    var scripts = ["script1.js", "script2.js", "script3.js"];
    for (i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        var element = document.createElement("script");
        element.src = scripts[i];
        document.body.appendChild(element);
   }
}
```

Comment: It's the kind of thing I need but unfortunately that doesn't work.